# How to return ID of Ignite task to stop this task in the future?

Tags: ignite

I `broadcast` some Apache Ignite task for some entity with ID stored in DB of my app.
At some moment I want to stop this task (may be even after restart of my app).

For this I think that I need somehow to return UUID of this task (when I `broadcast` this task), save this task UUID near entity ID in DB of my app to stop this task in the future.

Here's how I can stop this task, if I know this task UUID (taskUuid) (scala code):

```
val clusterGroup = ignite$.cluster().forServers()
ignite$.compute(clusterGroup).broadcast(new IgniteRunnable {
  override def run(): Unit = {
    ignite$.compute().activeTaskFutures[Any]().asScala.filter(
      e => e._1.toString == taskUuid).foreach(e => e._2.cancel())
  }
})
```

So, my question is, how I can return this `taskUuid`, when I submit some task with `IgniteCompute.broadcast(...)` method?

Answer (score 2):

You can execute task asynchronously and get this information from the future (this is Java code, but can be easily mapped to Scala):

```
IgniteCompute asyncCompute = ignite.compute().withAsync();

asyncCompute.broadcast(new MyRunnable());

ComputeTaskFuture<?> future = asyncCompute.future();

IgniteUuid id = future.getTaskSession().getId();
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on Ignite version.

Since 2.0: You can use [IgniteCompute.broadcastAsync](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/2.0.0/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCompute.html#broadcastAsync(org.apache.ignite.lang.IgniteRunnable)), that returns IgniteFuture.

before 2.0: There is an [IgniteCompute.activeTaskFutures](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/1.9.0/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCompute.html#activeTaskFutures()) method that returns all currently running tasks executed by current node. You can use these futures to cancel tasks.

Comment: Evgenii, it seems that  IgniteCompute.activeTaskFutures will not work after node restart.

Comment: As I understand, async callback will execute only when `broadcast` was finished.
But it may be long-running operation, which I want to stop.
I know I can try to determine new submitted task with `activeTaskFutures`, but it would be inaccurate solution.